# Create a global stack navigator keeping history

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I would like to create a global stack navigator callable everywhere in the application, so, imagine a stack navigator :

```
export default createStackNavigator( //Nav A
    {
        Screen1: Screen1,
        Screen2: Screen2
    }
```

and a second :

```
export default createStackNavigator( //Nav B
    {
        Screen3: Screen3,
        Screen4: Screen4
    }
```

If i'm on screen2 and trying to navigate to the Screen3, it's working, but I lost the navigation history, in other way, I can't go back to screen2 using the header back button.

How should I handle this ?

Comment: did you try redux or mobx for state management?

Comment: No, i'm not using any state management librarie.

Comment: if you want you can use useHistory hook in React Router >5.1.0 if you are using React >16.8.0 if you don't want to use Redux or MobX

Comment: I'm using react-navigation as routing library.